# Пиксельная линейка в chrome

Tags: google-chrome, браузер

После переустановки Chrome пропала пиксельная линейка. Говорят, что ее как-то можно включить, если не врут, подскажите как. Спасибо.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- <kbd>F12</kbd> → сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.
- <kbd>F12</kbd> → вторая сверху слева кнопка панельки (Toggle Device Mode):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Чтобы включить также показ линий, ограничивающих элемент на этой линейке нужно включить опцию "Show Rulers". Жмём <kbd>F12</kbd> → <kbd>F12</kbd> и ставим галку в пункте General → Elements →  Show Rulers:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот что получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Можно не включать "Device Mode", тогда пиксельные линейки будут появляться только при инспектировании элемента.

Comment: Я видимо немного не корректно задал вопрос.
при наведении на элемент, например "body" как в скрине, раньше были границы этого элемента, ограниченные линиями по всей странице.

Comment: Примерно такие линии как в расширении page ruler

Comment: @АртемЧенцов Добавил в ответ.

Comment: То, что нужно. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @АртемЧенцов Не за что. Рад был помочь.